# How to Bold both number and list on HTML (OL LI) without getting the sub list getting affected?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to make a list like this picture, but I think I can't get it right.

[image]

I was able to bold only the list but I couldn't bold the number generated by using , also I want to know how to get the exact result on  like on the picture.

Here is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Pertemuan 03</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    h4 {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    .italic {
      font-style: italic;
    }
    
    ul li,
    ol li {
      text-indent: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h4>Menu:</h4>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <b>Makanan:</b>
      <ol type="A">
        <li>Nasi Kuning</li>
        <li>Nasi Uduk</li>
        <li>Nasi Goreng</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <b>Lauk:</b>
      <ul type="disc">
        <li>Tahu Goreng</li>
        <li>Tempe Goreng</li>
        <li>Orek Tempe</li>
        <li>Cah Kangkung</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <b>Sayur:</b>
      <ol type="a">
        <li>Sayur Asem</li>
        <li>Soto Ayam</li>
        <li>Sop Iga Sapi</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <b>Minuman:</b>
      <ol type="A">
        <li>
          <i>Minuman Dingin:</i>
          <ol type="i">
            <li>Es Teh Manis</li>
            <li>Es Jeruk</li>
            <li>Es Campur</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <br>
        <li>
          <i>Minuman Panas:</i>
          <ol type="i">
            <li>Kopi Hitam</li>
            <li>Lemon Tea</li>
            <li>Hot Chocolate</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

I am sorry if this question are confusing, because i cant explain it well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Now this code displays exactly the same as your picture**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Pertemuan 03</title>
<style>
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h4 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}

ol {
    font-weight: lighter;
    
    

}

ul {
    font-weight: lighter;
    
}

.main-list{
    text-indent: 20px;
   
    
    

}
.main-list > li::before {
  content: none;
}

.main-list > li {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h4>Menu:</h4>
<ol class="main-list">
 <li><b>Makanan:</b>
  <ol type="A">
    <li>Nasi Kuning</li>
    <li>Nasi Uduk</li>
    <li>Nasi Goreng</li>
  </ol>
 </li>
 <li><b>Lauk:</b>
   <ul type="disc">
    <li>Tahu Goreng</li>
    <li>Tempe Goreng</li>
    <li>Orek Tempe</li>
    <li>Cah Kangkung</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><b>Sayur:</b>
  <ol type="a" >
    <li>Sayur Asem</li>
    <li>Soto Ayam</li>
    <li>Sop Iga Sapi</li>
  </ol>
 </li>
 <li><b>Minuman:</b>
  <ol type="A">
    <li>
      <i>Minuman Dingin:</i>
      <ol type="i" >
        <li>Es Teh Manis</li>
        <li>Es Jeruk</li>
        <li>Es Campur</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      <i>Minuman Panas:</i>
      <ol type="i" >
        <li>Kopi Hitam</li>
        <li>Lemon Tea</li>
        <li>Hot Chocolate</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
 </li>
 </ol>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Style the `::marker` and reset the `::marker` in the sub-menus.

```css
li::marker {
  font-weight: bold;
}

li li::marker {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Pertemuan 03</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    h4 {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    .italic {
      font-style: italic;
    }
    
    ul li,
    ol li {
      text-indent: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h4>Menu:</h4>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <b>Makanan:</b>
      <ol type="A">
        <li>Nasi Kuning</li>
        <li>Nasi Uduk</li>
        <li>Nasi Goreng</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <b>Lauk:</b>
      <ul type="disc">
        <li>Tahu Goreng</li>
        <li>Tempe Goreng</li>
        <li>Orek Tempe</li>
        <li>Cah Kangkung</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <b>Sayur:</b>
      <ol type="a">
        <li>Sayur Asem</li>
        <li>Soto Ayam</li>
        <li>Sop Iga Sapi</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <b>Minuman:</b>
      <ol type="A">
        <li>
          <i>Minuman Dingin:</i>
          <ol type="i">
            <li>Es Teh Manis</li>
            <li>Es Jeruk</li>
            <li>Es Campur</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <br>
        <li>
          <i>Minuman Panas:</i>
          <ol type="i">
            <li>Kopi Hitam</li>
            <li>Lemon Tea</li>
            <li>Hot Chocolate</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

Alternatively, you don't need the `<b>` tags at all. Just reset the `font-weight` on the submenus.

```
ul li,
ol li {
  font-weight: bold;
}

li li {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h4 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}

ul li,
ol li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

li li {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<h4>Menu:</h4>
<ol>
  <li>
    Makanan:
    <ol type="A">
      <li>Nasi Kuning</li>
      <li>Nasi Uduk</li>
      <li>Nasi Goreng</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    Lauk:
    <ul type="disc">
      <li>Tahu Goreng</li>
      <li>Tempe Goreng</li>
      <li>Orek Tempe</li>
      <li>Cah Kangkung</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Sayur:
    <ol type="a">
      <li>Sayur Asem</li>
      <li>Soto Ayam</li>
      <li>Sop Iga Sapi</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    Minuman:
    <ol type="A">
      <li>
        <i>Minuman Dingin:</i>
        <ol type="i">
          <li>Es Teh Manis</li>
          <li>Es Jeruk</li>
          <li>Es Campur</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <br>
      <li>
        <i>Minuman Panas:</i>
        <ol type="i">
          <li>Kopi Hitam</li>
          <li>Lemon Tea</li>
          <li>Hot Chocolate</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Paulie, but how bout the indent after the number ? It does work on my list below my main list, but main list didn't have indent.. also for the list that using type i, how to style them to match the picture?

Comment: That's a separate question.

Comment: Should i make another question, or should i edit my question instead?

Comment: You should make a new question with appropriate code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Marker :::
The `:: Marker` CSS **Pseudo-Element** Selects The Marker Box of a List Item, which type of contains a bullet or number. IT WORKS on Any Element or Pseudo-Element Set to `Display: List-Item`, Such As The

And  Elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Pertemuan 03</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        h4 {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        .italic {
            font-style: italic;
        }

        ul li,
        ol li {
            text-indent: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 3px;
        }

        /* marker and select li by class*/

        .bold::marker {
            color: rgb(7, 7, 7);
            font-weight: 900;
            font-size: 1rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h4>Menu:</h4>
    <ol id="ol">
        <li class="bold">
            <b>Makanan:</b>
            <ol type="A">
                <li>Nasi Kuning</li>
                <li>Nasi Uduk</li>
                <li>Nasi Goreng</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="bold">
            <b>Lauk:</b>
            <ul type="disc">
                <li>Tahu Goreng</li>
                <li>Tempe Goreng</li>
                <li>Orek Tempe</li>
                <li>Cah Kangkung</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="bold">
            <b>Sayur:</b>
            <ol type="a">
                <li>Sayur Asem</li>
                <li>Soto Ayam</li>
                <li>Sop Iga Sapi</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="bold">
            <b>Minuman:</b>
            <ol type="A">
                <li>
                    <i>Minuman Dingin:</i>
                    <ol type="i">
                        <li>Es Teh Manis</li>
                        <li>Es Jeruk</li>
                        <li>Es Campur</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <br>
                <li>
                    <i>Minuman Panas:</i>
                    <ol type="i">
                        <li>Kopi Hitam</li>
                        <li>Lemon Tea</li>
                        <li>Hot Chocolate</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

The `marker` sees all the list-styles of your list.
**Hope this answer has been useful to you.**

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the exact formatting as shown in the picture, you can modify your HTML code by adding some additional CSS styling. Below is the updated code with the necessary modifications:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h4 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}

ul li,
ol li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.list-number {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Pertemuan 03</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h4>Menu:</h4>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <b>Makanan:</b>
        <ol type="A">
          <li>
            <span class="list-number">1.</span>Nasi Kuning
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="list-number">2.</span>Nasi Uduk
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="list-number">3.</span>Nasi Goreng
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        <b>Lauk:</b>
        <ul type="disc">
          <li>
            <span class="list-number">a.</span>Tahu Goreng
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="list-number">b.</span>Tempe Goreng
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="list-number">c.</span>Orek Tempe
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="list-number">d.</span>Cah Kangkung
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <b>Sayur:</b>
        <ol type="a">
          <li>
            <span class="list-number">i.</span>Sayur Asem
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="list-number">ii.</span>Soto Ayam
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="list-number">iii.</span>Sop Iga Sapi
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        <b>Minuman:</b>
        <ol type="A">
          <li>
            <i>Minuman Dingin:</i>
            <ol type="i">
              <li>
                <span class="list-number">1.</span>Es Teh Manis
              </li>
              <li>
                <span class="list-number">2.</span>Es Jeruk
              </li>
              <li>
                <span class="list-number">3.</span>Es Campur
              </li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <br>
          <li>
            <i>Minuman Panas:</i>
            <ol type="i">
              <li>
                <span class="list-number">1.</span>Kopi Hitam
              </li>
              <li>
                <span class="list-number">2.</span>Lemon Tea
              </li>
              <li>
                <span class="list-number">3.</span>Hot Chocolate
              </li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

I made a `.list-number` class containing the list numbers to the  elements.

I applied a CSS style to the list-number class to make the numbers bold and add a margin between the number and the list item text. This should give you the desired formatting for your list items, including bold numbers as shown in the picture.

Sorry if I didn't answer it right but according to your question and my understanding, I think this should be the right answer...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i think it didn't match the result that i wanted.